# android drag and drop issue

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have created a drag and drop activity in my app for reordering items using the code found [here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html).

one of the activities involves reordering images, so I added an image view to the layout and adjusted the code to add the right images and all that stuff. Everything works fine except that when grabbing items, the first item you grab from each slot is always what shows up whenever you grab any other item from that slot.

So for example, say i have items a, b, c, and d, if I grab item a and move it to the end, b is now in that first slot. if I grab item b now, the floating view that gets dragged around is still showing a. When it's dropped, everything looks fine and is in the new order that it is supposed to be in. Now in that same example, if I take the second item, which is now item c, and move it anywhere, the same thing happens. Dragging the first item always shows a and the second always shows c.

I can also take item a, move it to the second, then third, then fourth etc, slot and then no matter which item I grab, item a is always the one showing when an item is being dragged.

I'm confused as to what is causing this, i think it may be something to do with this section of code, specifically with the drawing Cache.

```
private void startDrag(int itemIndex, int y) {
    stopDrag(itemIndex);

    Log.i("startdrag","view " + itemIndex);

    View item = getChildAt(itemIndex);
    if (item == null) return;
    item.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    if (mDragListener != null)
        mDragListener.onStartDrag(item);

    // Create a copy of the drawing cache so that it does not get recycled
    // by the framework when the list tries to clean up memory
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(item.getDrawingCache());

    WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    mWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    mWindowParams.x = 0;
    mWindowParams.y = y - mDragPointOffset;

    mWindowParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    mWindowParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    mWindowParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
    mWindowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    mWindowParams.windowAnimations = 0;

    Context context = getContext();
    ImageView v = new ImageView(context);
    v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);      

    WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(v, mWindowParams);
    mDragView = v;
}
```

The original app also occasionally shows the wrong item when dragging, but I cannot get it to repeat reliably, which is why I think it has something to do with the drawing cache. My version has images and its probably trying to save memory by reusing the old views. I really don't know, if there's more I need to show just ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the drawing cache, try instead to get the bitmap from the view directly. This is how Google does it in their DynamicListView as you can see below. I've been using a lightly modified version of it without issue.  You can find more info here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q

```
/** Draws a white border over the screenshot of the view passed in. */
private Bitmap getBitmapWithBorder(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(v);
    Canvas can = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(LINE_THICKNESS);
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_white));

    can.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    can.drawRect(rect, paint);

    return bitmap;
}

/** Returns a bitmap showing a screenshot of the view passed in. */
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bitmap);
    v.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: cool, this works, and the example in the link looks better with the animations than what I have now, so I might just swap and try working with that code. Thanks!